# Merge firestore offline writes when device goes online

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We store device status in Firestore from an Android tablet. This could be if a printer is online or offline.

When the tablet goes offline for a while and comes back, we see a lot of write churn where each write for i.e a printer will be 'played back'. We are really only interested in seeing the last write for a given doc id. Is there a way to tell firebase that newer writes should completely replace older ones *before* hitting the server, once online?

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to tell Firebase that newer writes should completely replace older ones before hitting the server, once online?

Yes, there is. You should consider writing the data in the exact same location. When it comes to Cloud Firestore, you should always write the data in the same document. It doesn't really matter how many updates you do while offline, when the device regains connectivity, you'll only get the last update.